# Font size change section footer table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I'm currently building an iOS App in Swift and I got some problems. My settings view is a tableviewcontroller. It's a grouped one. My Table View is dynamic, fonts are dynamics.

I would like to interact to the change of font size from the settings app.

If my application was already running, the font size change but the layout is just broken. (change from the smallest to the biggest font)

Image : [Layout bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t61hl.png)

If I restart my app with the new font settings, there is no problems...

Here is a XCODE [project example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ch7e58f9a25cpv9/testDynamicTableView.zip?dl=0), you'll see the bug.

Could you please help me to find a solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that it's an iOS bug. I find the same bug in the Apple Apps.

The bug happens when you set the smallest font, quit the app and set the biggest font.

Thanks for your help.

[Bug Settings App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AC1J.png)

Answer (score 0):

After you change the font size try to call

`self.view.setNeedsLayout()`

it sets a flag in the UIView that marks it as needing layout change.

Also you can try to call

`self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Apple documentation says :

> Use this method to force the layout of subviews before drawing. Using the view that receives the message as the root view, this method lays out the view subtree starting at the root.

Hope that help you

Comment: My view controller is modal. If i close it and open a new one, the problem is still there :/

And my table view is completely dynamic. I'll try your solution in a few minutes btw

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've no problem with other table views which don't have section footer or header

Answer (score 0):

The `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` is what you're looking for.

Per the docs:

> Posted when the user changes the preferred content size setting.
>
> This notification is sent when the value in the
>   preferredContentSizeCategory property changes. The userInfo dictionary
>   of the notification contains the UIContentSizeCategoryNewValueKey key,
>   which reflects the new setting.

Example callback implementation:

```
 func handleContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
         self.questionLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
    }
```

Comment: "If my application was already running, the font size change"

So i'm already using it.